# Can't save database values in sessions php

Tags: php, mysql, web, authentication, backend

who can help me with, this is the code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}

require 'database.php';
$error='';

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,name,surname,username,password FROM users WHERE username =:username');

    $records->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
        $_SEESION['user_name'] = $results['name'];
        $_SEESION['user_surname'] = $results['surname'];
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        $error = 'Na vjen keq, username ose passowrd jane gabim !!';
    }

endif;
?>
```

The session user_id is saved normally and I can use it, but two other sessions user_name and user_surname are not beign saved, when I try to use them i get an error saying undefined 'user_name' and 'user_surname'

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

there is typo on `$_SEESION['user_name']` and `$_SEESION['user_surname']` change it to :

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $results['name'];
$_SESSION['user_surname'] = $results['surname'];
```